# Adding hyphen between words in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of values which looks like:

```
['Carter Copeland Melius Research LLC - Founding Partner, President and Research Analyst of Aerospace & Defense\n', 'Gregory D. Smith The Boeing Company - CFO and Executive VP of Enterprise Operations, Finance & Strategy\n', 'Maurita B. Sutedja The Boeing Company - VP of IR\n']
```

I want to add a hyphen after the name and this should look like:

```
['Carter Copeland - Melius Research LLC - Founding Partner, President and Research Analyst of Aerospace & Defense\n', 'Gregory D. Smith - The Boeing Company - CFO and Executive VP of Enterprise Operations, Finance & Strategy\n', 'Maurita B. Sutedja - The Boeing Company - VP of IR\n']
```

So the logic is that if there is a "." after the second word then the hyphen will be at the end of the third word or else the hyphen would be after the second word.

How do i do this?

Comment: You should use regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/fr/3.7/howto/regex.html you can use this https://regexr.com/ or https://regex101.com/ to test /learn your regex. Regex is an important skill to have for developers.

Comment: This will fail miserably if their name isn't exactly two words, like `Erich von Stahlhein` or `Fred J. Muggs` (or, heavens, `Sting`, or `Her Royal Majesty Queen Elizabeth II`)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names = ['Carter Copeland Melius Research LLC - Founding Partner, President and Research Analyst of Aerospace & Defense',
             'Gregory D. Smith The Boeing Company - CFO and Executive VP of Enterprise Operations, Finance & Strategy',
             'Maurita B. Sutedja The Boeing Company - VP of IR']

for index, name in enumerate(names):
    splitted = name.split(" ")
    if "." in splitted[1]:
        splitted.insert(3, "-")
    else:
        splitted.insert(2, "-")

    names[index] = " ".join(splitted)

print(names)
```

This should do the trick. But it only works when all names are following your mentioned schema.

Answer (score 2):

I did not fully understand the second type of sentence but i think this is waht you mean.

```
def add_hyphen(string):
    words = string.split(" ")
    if words[1][-1]==".":
        words.insert(3, '-')
    else:
        words.insert(2, '-')
    return ' '.join(words)

txt = ['Carter Copeland Melius Research LLC - Founding Partner, President and Research Analyst of Aerospace & Defense\n', 'Gregory D. Smith The Boeing Company - CFO and Executive VP of Enterprise Operations, Finance & Strategy\n', 'Maurita B. Sutedja The Boeing Company - VP of IR\n']


for k,string in enumerate(txt):
txt[k] = add_hyphen(txt[k])

print(new_txt)
['Carter Melius - Research LLC - Founding Partner, President and Research Analyst of Aerospace & Defense\n', 'Gregory D. Smith - The Boeing Company - CFO and Executive VP of Enterprise Operations, Finance & Strategy\n', 'Maurita B. Sutedja - The Boeing Company - VP of IR\n']
```

Comment: This works for the cases where there is no middle name. The second type wont work where names like "Robert D. Junior" comes up

Comment: works as well, the output is "Robert D. Junior - ..."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick regex I made:

```
(^\w* \w*([^.]|. \w*))
```

Replace with:

```
$1 -
```

You can try it there
https://regex101.com/r/JtjMuE/1

Here is auto auto generated code:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"(^\w* \w*([^.]|. \w*))"

test_str = ("Carter Copeland Melius Research LLC - Founding Partner, President and Research Analyst of Aerospace & Defense\n"
    "Gregory D. Smith The Boeing Company - CFO and Executive VP of Enterprise Operations, Finance & Strategy\\n")

subst = "$1 - "

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```